# Add and delete multiple rows from a table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a dynamic table in my `vue` app that adds or deletes rows when buttons are clicked. The table looks like this.

```
<table class="stripped centered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Part No.</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>unit market price</th>
            <th>Markup percentage</th>
            <th><a @click="addRow " class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-3 white-text">Add row</a></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="body-rows" v-for="(row, index) in tableRows" :key="index">
          <tr>
            <td><a @click.prevent="deleteRow(index)" class="waves-effect waves-light btn red darken-3 white-text"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i></a></td>
            <td><input class="item-no" type="number" step="0.001" placeholder="Item no"></td>
            <td><input class="part-no" type="text" placeholder="part no"></td>
            <td><input type="text" placeholder="description"></td>
            <td><input class="quantity" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="quantity"></td>
            <td><input class="ump" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="UMP"></td>
            <td><input class="markup" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="markup %"></td>
            <td><a class="add-sub waves-effect waves-light btn teal darken-3 white-text"><i class="material-icons left">add</i>sub</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="chip">Freight and Insurance</div></td>
            <td><div class="chip">Other costs</div></td>
            <td><div class="chip">Custom Rates</div></td>
            <td><div class="chip">Excise Tax</div></td>
            <td><div class="chip">VAT</div></td>
            <td><div class="chip">Surtax</div></td>
            <td><div class="chip">Withholding Tax</div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="freight & insurance"></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="other costs"></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="custom rates"></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="excise tax"></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="vat"></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="surtax"></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="withholding"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

As you see I am trying to add three rows in one iteration of the `v-for` loop. And in my script I have:

```
data(){
    return{
          currentRows: 0,
          tableRows: [],
    }
}
methods:{
    addRow(){
      this.currentRows++
      this.tableRows.push(this.currentRows)
    },
    deleteRow(index){
      this.tableRows.splice(index, 1)
},
```

The add button works and adds the three rows. But when I click the delete button on the row it deletes the last row instead of deleting it self. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why not directly use the `index` like `deleteRow(index)` and inside `deleteRow` do `this.tableRows.splice(index, 1)`?

Comment: @Minato ow this is something I tried when directly using `index` didn't work. They have the same results tho.

Comment: It could be that the comparator in `indexOf` return `-1` and the splice always removes a `row` from the end

Comment: @Minato I changed it back to using `index` directly and It still removes from the end

Comment: what is the structure of the `tableRows`

Comment: @Minato As you can see in the data it is first initialized as an empty list and then numbers will be pushed to it when add is clicked that make it look like `[1,2,3 ...]`

Comment: Ah, totally missed that, The iteration place is wrong, should be in <tr>

Comment: @Minato that only adds the first row. What I want to do is add 3 rows when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation would look like this

```
<table class="stripped centered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Part No.</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>unit market price</th>
        <th>Markup percentage</th>
        <th><a @click="addRow " class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-3 white-text">Add row</a></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="body-rows">
      <tr v-for="(row, index) in tableRows" :key=":key="JSON.stringify(row)"">
          <td>
            <table>
               <tr>
        <td><a @click.prevent="deleteRow(index)" class="waves-effect waves-light btn red darken-3 white-text"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i></a></td>
        <td><input class="item-no" type="number" step="0.001" placeholder="Item no"></td>
        <td><input class="part-no" type="text" placeholder="part no"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="description"></td>
        <td><input class="quantity" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="quantity"></td>
        <td><input class="ump" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="UMP"></td>
        <td><input class="markup" type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="markup %"></td>
        <td><a class="add-sub waves-effect waves-light btn teal darken-3 white-text"><i class="material-icons left">add</i>sub</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="chip">Freight and Insurance</div></td>
        <td><div class="chip">Other costs</div></td>
        <td><div class="chip">Custom Rates</div></td>
        <td><div class="chip">Excise Tax</div></td>
        <td><div class="chip">VAT</div></td>
        <td><div class="chip">Surtax</div></td>
        <td><div class="chip">Withholding Tax</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="freight & insurance"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="other costs"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="custom rates"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="excise tax"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="vat"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="surtax"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="withholding"></td>
      </tr>
            </table>
          </td>          
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Well that only iterates over one row only I want to add three rows on one iteration.

Comment: The table should have a single <tbody> so the parts you want to manipulate wrapped in the <tr> with the iteration so that serves as the focal for the splice when removing from the DOM

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing. wrapping all three `<tr>`s with `<tbody>` and iterating over them. Could you show me what you mean in the answer?

Comment: This should work but it is still deleting the last row. I don't understand what is wrong with it

Comment: change :key="index" to :key="JSON.stringify(row)" that should fix it. You can have a utility method to handle for cleaner experience. https://jsfiddle.net/4bpc0m2f/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code as follows

in deleteRow function call pass row id as well

```
   <td><a @click.prevent="deleteRow(row.id,index)" class="waves-effect waves-light btn red 
   darken-3 white-text"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i></a></td>
```

and delete method as follows

```
   deleteRow(id,index){
      this.tableRows.splice(id, 1);
      this.tableRows.splice(index, 1)
   }
```

Comment: This just deletes two rows from the end